# Toggle elements based on the selected row in the table in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am facing an issue where I am trying to use `b-collapse` in a table and when clicking on the button, it is currently collapsing all the rows in the table.

here is the code for it:

```
<table class="table b-table border">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="table-btn"></th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>last name</th>
            <th>address</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <td class="table-btn">
              <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1 variant="primary"
                >Toggle Collapse</b-button
              >
              <b-collapse id="collapse-1" class="mt-2">
                <b-card>
                  <p class="card-text">{{ item.id }}</p>
                </b-card>
              </b-collapse>
            </td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.address }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

and the script is:

```
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "John",
          lastname: "john@john.com",
          address: "test1",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "John2",
          lastname: "john2@john.com",
          address: "test2",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

How can I make it to toggle only the on clicking on the selected td/row of the table and display the details.

Here is a sample I am working on: [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-bhabha-v0xek?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It toggless all `b-collapse` components because you are using `v-for` and all `b-collapse` components has same `id` + all buttons are using this same `id` in a `v-b-toggle` directive.

So the solution is to assign different `id` for each row...

```html
<td class="table-btn">
  <b-button v-b-toggle="[`table_collapse_${idx}`]" variant="primary">Toggle Collapse</b-button>
  <b-collapse :id="`table_collapse_${idx}`" class="mt-2">
    <b-card>
      <p class="card-text">{{ item.id }}</p>
    </b-card>
  </b-collapse>
</td>
```

Comment: thanks alot @michal. is it posssible to toggle just below the row of the table. right now it is toggling in that ```td``` itself

Comment: @nsukhisingh Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-elements-based-on-the-selected-row-in-the-table-in-vuejs-7qk30) ?